# XSL for <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

Tags: xml, xslt

What will be the equivalent XSL style sheet for `<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

Comment: Show the code you are using.  If it works fine without a particular piece, why are you using that particular piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: The OP provided his code.

**Use**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="x:schema/x:element">
```

**Instead of**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="schema/element">
```

---

Search/read about "default namespace in XPath". This is a    **F  A  Q**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="/x:schema/x:a/x:b/x:c"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <a>
  <b>
   <c>d</c>
  </b>
 </a>
</schema>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
d
```

**Explanation**: Any unprefixed name in an XPath expression is always considered to be in "no namespace". If the XML document has a default namespace, then any element of this document is in the default namespace (not in "no namespace). Therefore, for such a document unprefixed names don't select any node -- because not a single node in this document is in "no namespace".

Comment: i am new .to xml and xsl, Please correct me if my understand is wrong

Comment: i need to search directly element instead of root ?

Comment: Your current XPath expression (with the prefix added to the element names) is a good one. You have to accept this answer now that your question has been answered completely and your code has also been corrected.

Comment: no its not working, my xml is as follows <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"..................../> and your xml as xmlns:x  so what we need to use for above xml in XSL

Comment: @revenna: Did you apply the changes to your code that I have proposed in the `U P D A T E` to my answer? If you had done this your code would be working as it is working for me. Read well my answer -- the UPDATE is at the very top.